# Issue with changing endpoint of an old Teams App and Bot

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I created a teams app for sending notifications from my application in 2022. I also had a proper bot handle in the Azure portal which was used to send proper notification messages to my Teams app using an endpoint that I declared in its settings. Recently, we have updated our application's URL and I need to update the endpoint of the bot as well. However, I'm unable to find the bot anywhere. It's neither in the Teams Developer's Portal nor in https://dev.botframework.com/bots. Due to this reason, my Teams App has stopped working. As per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/670277/why-cant-i-see-web-app-bot-in-the-market-place), "Web App Bot and Bot Channels Registration are deprecated but existing resources will continue to work". However, there is no mention of how to update the settings of an old, existing, working bot.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the bot in the Azure portal, as a Bot resource type. Inside there, in the Settings pane, there's a place to specify (or in this case to *change*) the endpoint

Comment: None of my previously created bots are listed. Neither in the Azure portal nor in https://dev.botframework.com/bots. That's the issue.

Comment: @Raj Do you have multiple tenants connected to your Azure account? Are you checking the correct tenant in the Azure Portal for your bots?

Comment: @AP01 No, I have only 1 tenant. Also, I can see all the running applications on App Registration, but the bots are not listed in the Bot Services. Moreover, the testing bot is running properly on my testing website but even that is missing from the Bot Services.

Comment: You'll probably need to reach out to your enterprise Azure admin (if applicable) or Azure Support. There's nothing we can do here on SO to fix this kind of issue.